# How can I scroll multiple DIVs in a slide-bar using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a beginner at jQuery and I have been trying to place more than one div in one slide bar. Basically, I am working on auction site and I want a DIV which displays more than one item in same div with *“Next”* and *“Previous”* button arrows.

**For example:**

When you visit an auction site, one slide-bar should appear containing more than one item (multiple DIVs). The slide-bar should have a text that appears, saying *“newly arrived item or recommended for you etc.”*

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this using jQuery? I have just recently started working with jQuery and I am stuck. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you put some code in your post?  and any errors?  since you are just starting out, check out the [StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to find out the best way to ask questions here.

Comment: Guys i already placed an image example for you, and I already mention that please not to markdown my question to negative, if you do not know the answer please do not mark down question negative

Comment: **Welcome!**  Since you're _freshers_, you should take a look at [**the StackOverflow FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about how to ask questions here, what kinds of questions are accepted and the info you need to include.  It might explain why you got the **downvotes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that “building your own” isn't an option for you, you could take a look at jQuery plugins like [Smooth DIV Scroll](http://smoothdivscroll.com/), or any alike plugin that scrolls content horizontally left or right.

Generally, one of the nice places to find a multitude of jQuery plugins would be (for example) the [jquery-plugins.net](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/horizontal-scroller) website. There you'll find usable plugins for what you're trying to do. Just one of many available there that also does what you're looking for: [Any List Scroller – jQuery Plugin To Scroll Lists](http://jquery-plugins.net/any-list-scroller-jquery-plugin-to-scroll-lists).

As said, there's more than a dozen alike plugins scattered all over the internet. All you need to do is to deciding which one fits your individual site best. In case of doubt, fire up your favorite search engine and look for “jquery div scroller”.